# Автоматическое перемещение обьекта

Tags: python, объекты, импорт, sleep

Не получается сделать так, чтобы обьект(например точка) двигалась по полю после нажатия кнопки. Точка должна двигаться вниз на 1 шаг с интервалом 0,5 сек. 
У меня выходит так, что точка оказывается уже в конечном пункте.

Возможно ли решить эту проблему без импорта других модулей?

```
from time import sleep

def create_board(width, height):
    board = []
    for row in range(0, height):
        board_row = []
        for column in range(0, width):
             if row == 0 or row == height-1:
                board_row.append("X")
            else:
                if column == 0 or column == width - 1:
                    board_row.append("X")
                else:
                    board_row.append(" ")
        board.append(board_row)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        for char in row:
            print(char, end='')
        print()


def insert_player(board, width, height):
    board[height][width] = '@'
    return board
```

Ниже пытаюсь добиться такого перемещения:

```
def wsad(board, char, x_pos, y_pos):
    while True:
        char == 's'
        move = True
        while move:
            if char == 's' and  " " in board[x_pos][y_pos +1]:
                    char == 's'
                    if char == 's' and  " " in board[x_pos][y_pos +1]: 
                        while True:
                            y_pos += 1
                            sleep(0.5)
                            move = False
                        break
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вам нужно. По какому полю?

Comment: Alban, добавил часть кода, чтобы было понятнее немного.

Comment: `while True` это бесконечный цикл. В чём у вас сложность? Вы не знаете как следующую позицию вычислить? (`y_pos +=1`) Не знаете как нарисовать точку на поле, зная её координаты? (если у вас только два объекта: поле и точка -- просто каждый раз заново их перерисовывайте). В сторону, `create_board()` можно упростить: `return [["X" if row in (0, height-1) or column in (0, width-1) else " " for column in range(width)] for row in range(height)]`. И напечатать: `print_board = lambda board: print(*map(''.join, board), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажеться этот код делает то что вам нужно:

```
import os
import time
import platform


class Board:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.board = []
        for _ in range(self.height):
            row = [' ' for _ in range(self.width)]
            self.board.append(row)

    def insert_player(self, cord):
        self.board[cord[0]][cord[1]] = '@'

    def move_player(self, src_cord, dst_cord, delay=0.2):
        src_width, src_height = src_cord
        dst_width, dst_height = dst_cord
        if self.board[src_width][src_height] != '@':
            raise ValueError('This player not capture: [{0}][{1}]'.format(src_width, src_height))
        while (src_width != dst_width) or (src_height != dst_height):
            self.board[src_width][src_height] = ' '
            if src_width > dst_width:
                src_width -= 1
            elif src_width < dst_width:
                src_width += 1
            if src_height > dst_height:
                src_height -= 1
            elif src_height < dst_height:
                src_height += 1
            try:
                self.board[src_width][src_height] = '@'
            except IndexError as exc:
                raise ValueError('Error when move player: {0}'.format(exc))
            self.print_board()
            time.sleep(delay)

    def clear_console(self):
        try:
            os.system(self.clear_command)
        except AttributeError:
            if 'Win' in platform.architecture()[1]:
                self.clear_command = 'cls'
            else:
                self.clear_command = 'clear'
            return self.clear_console()

    def print_board(self):
        self.clear_console()
        print(' '.join('X' for _ in range(self.width)))
        for row in self.board:
            col = 'X{0}X'.format(' '.join(row))
            print(col)
        print(' '.join('X' for _ in range(self.width)))


board = Board(10, 10)
board.print_board()
board.insert_player((2, 2))
board.move_player((2, 2), (8, 9))
board.print_board()
```